# Algebra 1: Distributive Law: Product of Two Binomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand the specific mathematical rules that are being used to expand and simplify the the product of two binomials. I can grasp how the distributive law would apply to the product of a mononomial and a binomial, but I'm not 100% sure that I'm correctly interpreting specifically how this applies to the product of two binomials.

E.g.

**Distributive Law states:**

A(B+C) = AB + AC

**Applied to mononomial x binomial**


Expand and simplify

(2x)(4x+5y)

2x = A
4x = B
5y = C

Therefore
(2x)(4x+5y)
= (2x)(4x)+(2x)(5y)
= $8x^2$ +10xy

**Applied to binomial x binomial**

Expand and simplify

(2x-3y)(4x+5y)

The only way I can make sense of this using the Distributive Law is if we think of it as letting (2x-3y) = A  in this scenario. If so, this raises the question what does A (or B or C for that matter) actually stand for in the formula i.e. a term, a single number, an expression, or all of those?

A = (2x-3y)
B = 4x
C = 5y

Therefore
(2x-3y)(4x+5y)
= (2x-3y)(4x)+(2x-3y)(5y)
= $8x^2$-12xy+10xy-$15y^2$
= $8x^2$-2xy-$15y^2$

I'd be really grateful for any explanations. I really just want to make sure I'm understanding what's really going on here at a fundamental level, and whether I'm missing something entirely or misinterpreting.

Comment: $A$ can stand for anything. And note that for your two binomials you have to use distributivity three times. You identified the first time correctly, but then you have to use it twice to get from the second to third line, and you have to use the form (A-B)C = AC - BC. And of course A, B, and C represent different xy expressions each time you use the rule.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering and for noting that we are using the distributive law 3 times , which as I now understand involves 
1st time (2x-3y)(4x+5y) 
= (2x-3y)(4x) + (2x-3y)(5y)
= 2nd time (4x)(2x) + (4x)(-3y) + 3rd time (5y)(2x) +(5y)(-3y)
I also see you wrote that you have to use the form (A-B)C = AC – BC
I understand this intuitively and of course can see that it works out, but can you explain why we are actually able to rewrite using negatives?

Comment: It's something you can prove from the addition version, and we use the fact that A-B = A + (-B). And that is because, well, in advanced algebra it's usually just the definition of subtraction. But in beginning algebra you might take subtraction as another basic operation, in which case you either have to add a subtraction version of distributivity to your rules, or prove the relationship between subtraction and negatives.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in your expansion. Let's go through it. Given the expression: $(2x-3y)(4x+5y)$

Let's denote:

$$
\begin{align*}
A &= (2x-3y)\\
B &= 4x\\
C &= 5y.
\end{align*}
$$

Now, applying the distributive law and expanding:
$$
\begin{align*}
A(4x) + A(5y) &= (2x-3y)(4x+5y)\\
              &= (2x-3y)(4x) + (2x-3y)(5y)
\end{align*}
$$
Now, applying the distributive law again, and simplifying:
$$
\begin{align*}
4x(2x) - 3y(4x) + 5y(2x) - 3y(5y) &= 8x^2 - 12xy + 10xy - 15y^2 \\
                                  &= 8x^2 - 2xy - 15y^2.
\end{align*}$$

So, the correct expansion is:
$$(2x-3y)(4x+5y) = 8x^2 - 2xy - 15y^2.$$

Your idea of treating $(2x-3y)$ as a single term $A$ make and then applying the distributive law within each term is correct. Just be careful with the signs when combining like terms while simplifying.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer and for confirmation that we can substitute the whole expression (2x-3y) for A. Also thanks for writing out in full that we use the distributive law again going from
(2x−3y)(4x)+(2x−3y)(5y)
to
4x(2x)−3y(4x)+5y(2x)−3y(5y)
Which from what I understand is just subbing the values into that formula again 
= AB + AC 
= AB + CA + AB + CA

Comment: @spideog you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

We have to expand $(2x - 3y)(4x + 5y)$.

Let’s first define:

$A = 2x - 3y$

$B = 4x$

$C = 5y$

Now, we can take the distributive property formula:

$A(B + C) = AB + AC$

And plug in our values:

$(2x - 3y)(4x + 5y) = (2x - 3y)4x + (2x - 3y)5y$

Now, you can use the normal monomial vs. binomial distributive property to simplify:

$8x^2 - 12xy + 10xy - 15y^2 \implies 8x^2 - 2xy - 15y^2$

Hence, letting $A$ equal an expression does work.

Usually, a placeholder like $A$ can have different meanings according to context. It may be a scalar (scalar is basically a fancy word for number), an expression, so on, depending on what you’d plug in.

---

For binomial vs. binomial, we typically use a method called foiling to expand. While the distributive property you used is fine, the following is the formula for expanding a product of binomials:

$(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$

We can derive this by using the normal distributive property:

Let $A = a + b$, $B = c$, $C = d$.

Then we’d have:

$(a + b)(c + d) = (a + b)c + (a + b)d$

Which we can simplify using the distributive property as:

$(a + b)(c + d) = ac + bc + ad + bd$

Which we can just rearrange as

$ac + ad + bc + bd$

That’s how foiling is derived.

Maybe you learned about the expansion of $(a + b)^2$ before, which we can derive by foiling:

$(a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

In general, we use foiling for the product of binomials.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, particularly for noting how A can have different meaning depending on context. I had heard of the FOILING technique, but was keen to understand the what was actually happening at a fundamental level which was why I wanted to understand in terms of the distributive law.

Comment: @spideog I also added an explanation for how foiling is derived. Hope it helps too.